# Manually control check box value (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I want to be able to manually control value of check box.
I don't want its checked/unchecked state to be tied to the clicks.
I mean I want to handle click events anyway but I would like to myself update the checked/unchecked state from the click - and prevent the check box from doing so automatically.

restriction: I can't use a controlled component yet (due to some reasons).

For example I want such feature: when user checks a checkbox I want to restrict her from unchecking it. Attempt below to implement it doesn't work:

```
<input
id={chId}
type="checkbox"
onClick={(e) => {
     let value = document.getElementById(chId).checked;
     e.stopPropagation();
     if(value != false)
         document.getElementById(chId).checked = value;
}}

/>
```

The reason I want to be able to achieve this is I want say during some period of time to restrict the user from unchecking the check box. That is why I want to have full manual control over the checked state of check box.

Comment: Can you see what the "checked" state of the input is after your `onClick` handler executes? Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: @HoriaComan it says it is false; it was supposed to be true, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.preventDefault()` is freezing the checkbox. You need to remove it.

And it's `value`, not `!value`.

```
<input
id={chId}
type="checkbox"
onClick={(e) => {
     let value = document.getElementById(chId).checked;

     e.stopPropagation();

     if (restrictUser) {
       e.preventDefault();
     }

     document.getElementById(chId).checked = value;
}}

/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I use below code: http://codepad.org/avXMbyq6, to restrict user from unchecking the check box, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
      id={chId}
      type="checkbox"
      checked={(e) => !e.target.value}
    />
```

If you could explain the logic you want to use to check the box it might be easier to help you. Regardless, you should be able to replace the logic in the checked attribute and make it work, like you were trying to do in the onClick attribute.

Comment: For example during some period I want to restrict the user from unchecking the check box.

Comment: Then you could just add a disabled attribute.

Comment: so...`<input id={chId} type="checkbox" checked={(e) => !e.target.value}  disabled={some condition ? true : false} />`

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: I avoided this altogether and took different route which didn't require what my question was about. But one solution I found still was to: if user clicked a marked check box I deliberately again set its value to marked (because my goal was to prevent user from unchecking a checkbox-for some time).

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by state like
    contructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {checked: flase}
    }
    .
    .

```
<input
  id={chId}
  type="checkbox"
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onClick={(e) => {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
  }}
/>
```

Comment: that is controlled component I mentioned in question I can't use controlled component. But thanks for trying to help.